# Replacing string with line number in a file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am replacing all exit code with the line number of a bash script.

Sample file:

```
echo something
if conditional;then exit 1;fi
echo something else
if conditional;then exit 2;fi
```

Sample output:

```
echo something
if conditional;then exit 2;fi
echo something else
if conditional;then exit 4;fi
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
cat -n file |sed "s/\([[:blank:]]*[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)\(exit[[:blank:]]*\)\([0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/\1\2\3\1\5/" | sed "s/[[:blank:]]*[0-9]\+[[:blank:]]//"
```

Which does the job but it seems too complex for a simple task.

Any suggestions how I can do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this much simpler awk command:

```
awk '{sub(/\<exit[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+/, "exit " NR)} 1' file
echo something
if conditional;then exit 2;fi
echo something else
if conditional;then exit 4;fi
```

- `NR` represents current record # or line #
- `\<exit [0-9]+` is used to match `exit <digits>` where `\<` is for word boundary

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat -n file | sed -r 's/^(\s*(\S*).*exit\s)[0-9]+/\1\2/;s/^\s*\S*\t//'
```

or using a couple of applications of sed rather than `cat -n` and sed:

```
sed '/exit\s[0-9]/=' file | sed -r 'N;s/^(\S+)\n(.*exit\s)[0-9]*/\2\1/;P;D'
```